# passing a dynamic value in between get api url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

How to pass a dynamic value in between get api url?

I have a ref that is connected to the input and want  value of that input to be passed into a string.
This does not work:

```
const location = useRef("Warsaw");
"http://api.weatherstack.com/current?&query={location.current.value}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect dynamic string syntax. You should use template literals:

```
const location = useRef("Warsaw");

let url = `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?&query=${location.current.value}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literals

```
const location = useRef("Warsaw");

const uri = `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?&query=${location.current.value}`
```